# Angular/fire authState.subscribe not respond to logout

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to authenticate with firebase. I already build the login/register and logout. It works fine now, but now I want to display a navbar(a completely separate component) that has a login button and logout button. I need to toggle these buttons according to the user's authState. So I used subscribe on authState. But it only works when the user logs in. It does not trigger when the user logout. It is supposed to return null when a user logout right? I checked the authState inside the authService, it's null after the user logged out. So what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code.

#### auth.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    
    export class AuthService {
      authState: any;
    
      constructor(
        public db: AngularFirestore,
        public mAuth: AngularFireAuth
      ) {}
    
      getAuthState() {
        return this.mAuth.authState;
      }
      doLogout() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            this.mAuth.auth.signOut();
            resolve();
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        });
      }

    /* login, register, etc... */

    }
```

#### nav.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
    })
    export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    
      user: any;
    
      constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.authService.getAuthState().subscribe( user => {
          /* this doesn't respond to logout ... */
          console.log(user);
          this.user = user;
        });
      }
      tryLogout() {
        this.authService.doLogout()
          .then(res => {
            console.log('tryLogout', res);
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }, err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on Stackblitz? the authState should emit a value on logout.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfyqou?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts check this out. sample login : asdf@asf.com asdfasdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your authService `doLogout()` is returning a promise of a promise.

`auth.signout()` already returns a promise.

I think that your `doLogout()` function should just be:

```
return this.mAuth.auth.signout()
```

**Sidenote** : I ran into this exact same problem, and it was because authstate is somehow affected by `router.navigate`. My mistake was:

```
this.authstate.signout();
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

But with the above code, the `authstate` would never actually change. What fixed the problem was:

```
this.authstate.signout().then(this.router.navigate(['/'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between:

```js
authState.subscribe((user: any) => {
  if (user) {
    // logged in
  }
});
```

and

```js
onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
  if (user) {
    // logged in
  }
});
```

as the latter will return the correct state after logout...